# Select statement on same server and database produces a different result for 2 users on MariaDB

Tags: mariadb

We have a cluster of 8 nodes running MariaDB 10.5.

Why would this statement produce different results for 2 users?

select count(*) from schemaA.table where col in  (select col from schemaB.table where col = 'abc');

When I run this as root I get 0 rows.
But when I run this as userX with all privileges I get 100 rows.

Does anyone have an explanation for this?

Thanks

Comment: That depends. Can you share more details about this? Why does that root user not have all privileges?

Comment: @NicoHaase root and user 2 has all privileges. It seems to have something to do with user profiles on the OS as well.